# jqGrid 4 with jQuery 1.6.1

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

is there anyone who have experienced problems using the latests jQuery version with one of the last **jqGrid** releases?

I am in process to upgrade **jQuery** to **1.6.1** and I was trying to find infos about jqGrid but it seems that they are not yet supporting it.

**UPDATE:**

I did some tests and it seems that there are problems:
[image]

This is the script I've used:

```
var MyGrid = jQuery("#GroupsGrid");
MyGrid.jqGrid({
    url: '/Home/FetchData',
    postData: { Query: 'aaa' },
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: ['Nome'],
    colModel: [
           { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', sortable: false, width: 730 }
          ],
    pager: '#GroupsPager',
    rowList: [15, 30, 50],
    rowNum: 15,
    width: 794,
    height: 350,
    rownumbers: true
});
MyGrid.navGrid('#GroupsPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: true, search: false }, {}, {}, {});
```

UPDATE:

If I change the pager this way

```
MyGrid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#GroupsPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: true, search: false }, {}, {}, {});
```

I get this error: `uncaught exception: jqGrid - No such method: navGrid`

This is the JSON returned:

```
{"total":1,"page":1,"records":3,"rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["Alberto"]},{"id":"2","cell":["Paolo"]},{"id":"3","cell":["Alessandro"]}]}
```

Since I am using ASP.NET MVC2 I include my js/css files this way:

**Site.Master**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
    <link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

As you can see I've used a new placeholder so I can include my page-scripts in the head:

**Home/Index.aspx**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Head" runat="server">
    <link href="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
    <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jqGrid/i18n/grid.locale-it.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var MyGrid = jQuery("#GroupsGrid");
            MyGrid.jqGrid({
                url: '/Home/FetchData',
                postData: { Query: 'aaa' },
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'POST',
                colNames: ['Nome'],
                colModel: [
                       { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', sortable: false, width: 730 }
                      ],
                pager: '#GroupsPager',
                rowList: [15, 30, 50],
                rowNum: 15,
                width: 794,
                height: 350,
                rownumbers: true
            });
            MyGrid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#GroupsPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: true, search: false }, {}, {}, {});
    });
    </script>    
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div>
    <table id="GroupsGrid"></table>
    <div id="GroupsPager"></div>    
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I would not recommend to use jQuery 1.6.0 - only jQuery 1.6.1. I make all demos which I write here with jqGrid 4.0.0 and jQuery 1.6.1 and till now I found no problems.

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks. Actually, I was trying to use jQuery 1.6.1 but I've started to have a couple of problems. I didn't investigate, though. Do you have a link to one of your demos?

Comment: @Oleg: I've put together a very simple test just to see how it worked and it seems that there are some problems. The grid is rendered but I keep on getting a couple of errors.

Comment: Could you post test JSON data which follows to the error. In your example try to change `MyGrid.navGrid(...` to `MyGrid.jqGrid('navGrid','#GroupsPager', {edit:false, add:false, search:false});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but I could not reproduce your problem. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LeftyX_jQuery161.htm). I use HTTP "GET" instead of "POST" because I use no active server components. Could you verify the demo in your environments?

Comment: @Oleg: You can't reproduce the problem simply cause it works with your js file. I've downloaded it from the main site (complete with all the plug-ins). You are the jqGrid guy ;-) I guess you've changed yours.

Comment: @LeftyX: I use standard jqGrid without any changes. You can compare it with th version which you downloaded from [trirand](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6). Probably you have problem because you included too many JavaScripts or use it in the wrong order. Chould you append your question with the HTML page which you use or at list with the full list with the exact order of JavaScript files which you use.

Comment: @LeftyX: I downloaded jqGrid from [trirand site](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) and compared the `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` file with the file `http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.0.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js` which I used in my demo. The files are identical.

Comment: @Oleg: Yes, you're right.I did the same and it's exactly the same. I don't know what happened.I'll investigate further.

Comment: @LeftyX: Is your site is accessile from the internet? I chould tried to debug it. If not you should append your question with the exact list of JavaScript files which you includes on the page. I think it must be the key to your problem.

Comment: @Oleg: I am afraid not. It's on my machine and I have no chance to publish it. Problem now is it works even with the version I've downloaded from Trirand site ... and I haven't change a single line. I've cleaned the cache different time. I don't know what to think. I am embarrassed.

Comment: @LeftyX: It sounds really strange. You use `mtype: 'POST'` so the chaching problem could exist only with JavaScript or HTML files and not with the data. I can only suggest at the third time to include the exact list of JavaScript files which you includes on the page. Probably you have one existing problem and I could do help. Additionally chould be important which web browser you use in you tests.

Comment: @Oleg: thanks for your support. I'll put the list of js files in my question. I test everything with IE8, Firefox 4, Chrome 11 and sometimes Opera and Safari, latest versions.